# Access database on Amazon cloud using perl DBI and SSH modules

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, dbi, ssh-tunnel

I have a MySQL database on Amazon Cloud. I want to establish SSH connection using SSH Perl lib to connect to remote server and then use DBI to query db on that server. Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use DBI;
use Net::SSH::Perl;
use Class::ErrorHandler;
use warnings;

#key file
my @KEYFILE = ("path/to/pem/file");
$ENV{HOME} = "C:/Users/PC";

# remote server info
my $host = "54.68.xxx.xxx";
my $user = "ec2-user";
my $port="22";
my $cmd="ls -l";

# create connect to server 
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host, debug=>1, identity_files=>\@KEYFILE);
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);

# create connect to db 
my $s_dsn = "dbi:mysql:test:localhost:3306";
my $s_dbh = DBI->connect($s_dsn, "test","password");
```

I got the error **Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'**.

I don't know if DBI supports SSH connection or session? How to connect to db on remote machine after establishing SSH connection to that server? Could anyone help me in this case?

Comment: First you should make ssh tunnel to remote mysql server.

Comment: @mpapec: How to make ssh tunnel to make DBI aware?

Comment: http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html in case that `Net::SSH::Perl` doesn't support it.

Comment: @mpapec: How to establish ssh tunnel in Perl code?